# How to find record using $type in mongodb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am using ruby on rails with MongoDB. I have one field 'possession' as string type field. I've updated it as 'Integer'.

Now, I want to find old data with specific string(for example, '6') and need to update all as integer values(means 6).

So, instead of doing each loop on all record I will just distinct values and update_all based on distinct values.

Please let me know if anyone has idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

To find data using [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) you can use type value as `2` for `string`. And using `forEach` function you can update the records.

You can use this query:

```
db.collection.find({
  possession: {
    $type: 2
  }
}).forEach(function(data){
  db.collection.update({
    "$set": {
      "possession": parseInt(data.possession)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I want a query for update_all in rails. For example, if I got distinct as ['1', '3', '4'] then just I have to run 3 queries for update_all '1' to 1, '3' to 3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Mayuri has the right idea, but unfortunately did not test their answer.  I get an error when I run their code.  here is a fix to their solution.  I used mongo shell to test...

I also took the liberty of using the $type string name instead of a number code.

```
db.collection.find({
  possession: {
    $type: "string"
  }
}).forEach(function(data){
  db.collection.update({"_id":  data._id}, {
    "$set": {
      "possession": parseInt(data.possession)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but I don't want to do set on each record. I have very big numbers of collections(up to 4-5 lacs). So, I will just fetch distinct values from DB and update_all using the rails query. for example, if I got distinct as ['1', '3', '4'] then just I want to 3 queries for update all '1' to 1, '3' to 3 and so on.

Comment: @Pooja - This query does not iterate the entire collection.  It only iterates over documents which the value is of type string.  I presume this condition is rare.  You have not provided any metrics describing the scope of the problem.